# ListPicker missing

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listpicker

Consider I'm a newbie in WP7-Silverlight development, so please be patient if I'm asking something really stupid.
Yesterday I decided to start studying WP7, so on my

- Windows Seven 64bit
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1

I installed all the required tools:

- Windows Phone 7 SDK 7.1
- Windows Phone 7 SDK 7.1.1 patch

Watching some Microsoft guide I saw ComboBox control that's now missing as you can read in

- [Drop Down List Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356330/drop-down-list-windows-phone-7)
- [Problem with Windows Phone ComboBox Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686827/problem-with-windows-phone-combobox-style)

So I downloaded [Silverlight 5 Toolkit - December 2011](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435) and installed it.
Curiously when I start a new WP7-Silverlight application I can't see `ListPicker` in my toolbox.
So I tried to manually load it in toolbox referencing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Bin\System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll`, but I get an error stating it's missing some references.
It's something I'm doing wrong, I'm sure... but I really don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListPicker exists in Windows Phone toolkit, you downloaded the wrong binaries from codeplex, 
[Follow this link](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888)